# Slick 2.1 Code generator for MySQL : ClassNotFoundException on driver

Tags: mysql, scala, slick

I am trying to generate the `Table` classes from an existing SQL tables in MySQL.

I am using `Slick 2.1 (slick_2.11-2.1.0-M2)`, `mysql-connector-java-5.1.31-bin`

I have created a simple Scala file:

```
object MySQLPlayground {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        scala.slick.model.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator.main(
            Array("scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/fannuaire", "src/main/scala", "modelGene", "user", "password")
        )
    }
}
```

But it seems the driver path is wrong. I have the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/reflect/runtime/package$
    at scala.slick.model.codegen.SourceCodeGenerator$.main(SourceCodeGenerator.scala:60)
    at com.scala.mysql.MySQLPlayground$.main(MySQLPlayground.scala:10)
    at com.scala.mysql.MySQLPlayground.main(MySQLPlayground.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.reflect.runtime.package$
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 8 more
```

Since the doc says :

> Slick’s code generator comes with a default runner that can be used
>   from the command line or from Java/Scala.

I was expecting it to work out of the box.

Is there any other set up I have to do? Is the driver's path correct?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure but probably you have a typo when defining the driver, you wrote twice `.MySQLDriver`

Comment: Sorry, it' s my mistake. It still doesnt work with 1 `.MySQLDriver`. I have updated the code

Comment: I'm out of guesses then, sorry.

Comment: From the 2.0.2 version, both ways are possible. I tried with an old version and if I pass the user/password, the command returns the description of the argument types (user/password are not accepted of course) http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.2/code-generation.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please add scala-reflect to your code generator project dependencies.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang" % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
```

Comment: Yes, it works. I had `scala-reflect:2.10.3` in my dependencies (via some other jars I am importing from sbt) but the generator didn't work. And I am running on scala 2.10.2. Adding `scala-reflect 2.10.2` fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: It is recommended to upgrade to 2.10.4. Especially if you are using HLists.